# log4j2 suppress appender exception

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using a Socket appender, like this

```
<Socket name="Socket" host="localhost" port="24224" reconnectionDelay="5000" immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                <alwaysWriteExceptions>false</alwaysWriteExceptions>
                <Pattern>
                    {"key": "value"}
                </Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Socket>
```

However in some environments, the server is not installed and I get an exception in the logs

```
2023-08-04 13:56:58,708 main ERROR TcpSocketManager (TCP:localhost:24224) caught exception and will continue: java.io.IOException: Unable to create socket for localhost at port 24224 using ip addresses and ports , 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:24224
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager$TcpSocketManagerFactory.createSocket(TcpSocketManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager$TcpSocketManagerFactory.createManager(TcpSocketManager.java:475)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager$TcpSocketManagerFactory.createManager(TcpSocketManager.java:456)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.getSocketManager(TcpSocketManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.createSocketManager(SocketAppender.java:443)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender$Builder.build(SocketAppender.java:221)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender$Builder.build(SocketAppender.java:195)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1002)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:934)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:241)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:288)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:579)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:668)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:581)
    at p_outils.httptest_0_1.httpTest.<clinit>(httpTest.java:59)
```

How can I suppress these errors? Or tell log4j2 not to instantiate this appender based on an environment variable?

Comment: If this is running on an application server like Tomcat, it should be possible to configure some of the appenders in a per-server log file, and some in your application code. Otherwise, perhaps you can deploy the logging config file per server separately, instead of including it in the jar/war file.

Comment: Actually the tool using this is Talend ETL, and I don't have much control over it, I can just modify the log4j xml configuration file and pass some variables to the java command if necessary

Comment: But that's enough, right? Just make sure that the socket appender is only included right environment's config files

Comment: No actually, the Talend job (which is a java program) is built once by the developer and deployed to different environments. So ideally someone can suggest how to suppress these errors for environments where the socket appender can't connect to the server